# Need to remove padding around elements within Body

Tags: html, css, image, styles, padding

I am new to HTML5. I used to code HTML years ago, but I am not familiar with the new ways of doing things. I'm basically starting from scratch. I have started a design and the beginnings of code for a website I want to put up. Before I go farther, I wanted to get what I have done looking properly. There is padding around each image that I'm am unsure of how to remove. I need all images to put up against each other. I've tried putting padding: 0 and margin: 0 on all elements in the code, but nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

[Images with padding I want removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqq8y.png)

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
    <style>
    html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
    </style>
    </head>
  <body>

  <header>
  <img src="images/logo.gif" />
  </header>

  <nav>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <img src="images/purpleBarLeftOfNav.gif" width="173" height="77" alt="" title="" />
  <img src="images/navHomeTopSel.gif" alt="Home" title="" />
  <img src="images/navAboutTop.gif" alt="About" title="" />
  <img src="images/navServicesTop.gif" alt="Services" title="" />
  <img src="images/navPortfolioTop.gif" alt="Portfolio" title="" />
  <img src="images/navContactTop.gif" alt="Contact" title="" />
  <img src="images/purpleBarPgTitleHome.gif" alt="Home" title="" />
  </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td>
  <img src="images/spacerWhite.gif" width="114" height="146" alt="spacer" title="" />
  <img src="images/phoneEmail.gif" width="59" height="146" alt="Phone and Email" title="" />
  <img src="images/navHomeBtmSel.gif" width="32" height="146" alt="Home" title="" />
  <img src="images/navAboutBtm.gif" width="32" height="146" alt="About" title="" />
  <img src="images/navServicesBtm.gif" width="32" height="146" alt="Services" title="" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
```

Comment: `img {padding:0; margin:0}`? `img {display:inline-block;}`?

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov not sure why your comment was upvoted, it [doesn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/kez86p52/).

Comment: @LGSon, @hungerstar, well, it should be `img {float:left; } table {border-collapse:collapse} td {padding:0;margin:0}`. And `img {margin:0}` won't hurt either. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/voxn1wrp/)

Comment: I'm curious, why `img { margin: 0; }`?

Comment: @hungerstar, for the case if some browser decides to set a default margin =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<table>` and `<img>` based layout/design is probably not the best direction to be heading these days.

To answer your question you're likely seeing white space from a couple of places.

1. Spaces between table cells - use `border-collapse: collapse;` to remove. You might have to remove padding from the table cells as well.
2. Space around images - images are inline elements and as such have space for descenders, the parts of a letter form that fall below the baseline, and space around the image as well (at least if there's space between the `<img>` in your markup. Since you have images in a row you can float them or use [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to get rid of the space around them. In other instances you'd want to make the images `display: block;` to remove the inline white space.

#### Example 1 - What you likely have

```css
td {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ffcc00">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ffcc00">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Example 2 - More modern approach, NO TABLES with FLEXBOX

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="flex">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ffcc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/aacc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ffcc00">
  </div>

  <nav class="flex">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ffcc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/aacc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ffcc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/aacc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ffcc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/aacc00">
  </nav>

</header>
```

#### Example 3 - More modern approach, NO TABLES with FLOAT

```css
/* Clearfix to clear floats - http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="cf">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ffcc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/aacc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ffcc00">
  </div>

  <nav class="cf">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ffcc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/aacc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ffcc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/aacc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ffcc00">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/aacc00">
  </nav>

</header>
```

#### Example 4 - Old school with FLOAT

```css
td {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ffcc00">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/11cc00">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ffcc00">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Example 5 - Old school with FLEXBOX

```css
td {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ffcc00">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/11cc00">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ffcc00">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What will happen when you add more images in each cell? ... as in OP's sample

Comment: Without doing anything the images will stack vertically. To fix that the images would need to be floated or use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox). Currently as the OP I would be more concerned about having a layout that's based on tables and having a lot of the site's text locked up in images.

Comment: Hmm, the OP **does** have many images in a row, so how is that a different question?? ... just noticed the edit on your comment

Comment: Thank you!! Worked perfect :)

Comment: @LGSon yep, and my answer to address your concerns as well.

Comment: You are concerned about the OP using `table` for layout and still provide 3 samples using just that??

Comment: I can disagree with the approach, but doesn't mean that I cannot answer it as presented. I can show an uber simplified alternative version, doesn't mean OP will go down that road. They may very well stick with what they know in the end. So it's do I want to help with a specific question or go down this whole educational road of how to build a website in 2016. But I will change it just for you ;P.

Comment: Of course you can answer how ever you want, I just reacted on the fact that your were concerned about using `table` and didn't provide a sample without ... but I did so now that option is covered.

Answer (score 1):

Today, 2016, we use `flexbox` for layout, not `table` (unless you need to make it work on older browsers)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0
}
div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="114" height="146" alt="spacer" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="59" height="146" alt="Phone and Email" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="Home" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="About" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="Services" title="" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="114" height="146" alt="spacer" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="59" height="146" alt="Phone and Email" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="Home" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="About" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="Services" title="" />
</div>
```

And if you really can't use `flexbox`, just float them

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
div img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="114" height="146" alt="spacer" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="59" height="146" alt="Phone and Email" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="Home" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="About" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="Services" title="" />
</div>

<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="114" height="146" alt="spacer" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="59" height="146" alt="Phone and Email" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="Home" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="About" title="" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50" width="32" height="146" alt="Services" title="" />
</div>
```